Should I replace my curio cabinet bulb with LED or halogen?
I have a Sylvania CAPSYLITE 2PAR20 light bulb in my curio cabinet. The bulb needs to be replaced. It is 50w 120V NFL USA.
What’s better:  LED light replacement or a halogen replacement? The figures are crystals glued together and I’m concerned about too much heat from the bulb causing the pieces to come apart over time. Should I use a different bulb like LED or should I replace with what I have?

Things to consider: Check the CRI of the LEDs you plan to use. You'll want a high value, e.g. 90+. Incandescents often have a more uniform spread of light while many LEDs are more directional, particularly leaving a shadow at the base due to the driver module. Some LEDs (and some halogens) may emit more UV light than desired.

Almost any household bulb or tube should be replace with LED these days.
There's no real benefit to halogen bulbs. They use much more power, create much more heat, and probably even cost more initially anymore.

Initial cost may still be quite a bit higher for things like these PAR bulbs. But TCO including electricity definitely far lower for LED.

There is still a benefit to halogen if you have an old dimmer that needs a minimum draw to create stable power.
